# listview with textview and one button

Tags: android, button, android-listview

I have a `Listview` and in every row a `Button`. If I press the `Button` I want a `Toast` to be shown.

I already know how to set an `onItemClickListener` to my `List` but I don't know how to react to a single `Button` in the row. This is my code until now, it would be great if I don't need to change it a lot : )

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    if(arg2 == 0){                                  
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        String text = "Toast";
        Toast meinToast = Toast.makeText( context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        meinToast.show();                               
    }
}
```

Comment: Set an onClick listener on each button in your list adapter.  button.setOnClickListener(listener);

Answer (score 1):

In your Adapter try this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
    YourWrapper wrapper = null;

    if (row == null)
    {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, parent, false);
        wrapper = new YourWrapper (row);
        row.setTag(wrapper);
    }
    else
        wrapper = (YourWrapper) row.getTag();

    wrapper.getButton().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // What you want
        }
    });

    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `OnClickListener` for each button.

Please read this, then you will be able to create OnClickListeners and attach them to a button or other objects.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

In case there are issues when you wan't to implement the `OnclickListener()` try to write `View.OnClickListener.` The action that happens when the button is clicked goes to `OnClick(){//foo}` (will be generated automatically).

then just set the onclicklistener using `button.setOnclickListener(yourOnclickListener);`

Edit

```
Button mButton = ...

 mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //foo
            }
        });
```

Comment: THX... but as far as i can see, the informations here are very general about "How to create an OnClickListener for a Button". But my Problem is how to create an OnClickListener for a Button in a LISTVIEW???

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice tutorial how to use ListView with custom Adapter,

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

So you can use such function in custom Adapter class:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        final Button button = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.button_id);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
            }
        });
        return vi;
    }
```

if you add some more logic you can create custom event for each diplayed button in the list.